# Can Oracle VM be downloaded for free?

Tags: linux, virtualization, oracle, xen

I would like to try out Oracle VM just for fun.

Can it be downloaded for free from Oracle?

And if so, does anyone have a link?

Comment: I have done that now. Thanks for a really good answer.

Comment: Oracle VM is basically the same as the RedHat's VM, which is based on Xen. You can actually use CentOS as a replacement for either, as it is binary compatible with either, yet connecting to the update repository is free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it from the Downloads link on the [**Oracle VM home page**](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/virtualization/oraclevm/index.html).  Choose Enterprise Linux & VM from the Downloads menu.  Or [**this link**](http://edelivery.oracle.com/linux) will take you right to it.  Note you'll have to register as part of the download process.

(Also worth noting that [**VirtualBox**](http://www.virtualbox.org) is now Oracle's product and is free to download)

Answer (score -3):

Developers can download copies of the Oracle server, and the Oracle VM lives inside there.

---

This answer, while accepted, is sadly completely wrong. 
I was mislead by a comment into thinking that the JVM was at issue.

I can't delete it because it's accepted.

Comment: -1, I don't think this is correct. The *JVM* lives in the database. Oracle VM is a separate product. See @squillman's answer.